# How can I make the label of an edge displayed just in the middle position?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm trying to make the label displayed in the middle position, say `source --<sometext>--> target`.

I'm reading the official document but I can't find an answer.

Can this be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can see [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/tree/master/documentation/demos/labels), there is a simple solution to this provided by cytoscape:

```js
window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  layout: {
    name: 'grid',
    cols: 2
  },

  style: [{
      "selector": "node[label]",
      "style": {
        "label": "data(label)"
      }
    },
    {
      "selector": "edge[label]",
      "style": {
        "label": "data(label)",
        "width": 3,
        "text-background-opacity": 1,
        "text-background-color": "#fff"
      }
    },
    {
      "selector": ".autorotate",
      "style": {
        "edge-text-rotation": "autorotate",
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: [{
      data: {
        id: 'one'
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: 'two'
      }
    }, {
      data: {
        source: 'one',
        target: 'two',
        label: 'autorotate (move my nodes)'
      },
      classes: 'autorotate'
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Labels demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.3.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know the solution mentioned above before asking the question, what I really want is auto-rotated edge label while the line doesn't strike through the text.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer accordingly :) (text-margin-y is the right way to do this)

Comment: It doesn't work when two nodes are arranged vertically, I want to implement this effect as follows: [demo-graph](https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.assets.neo4j.com/wp-content/uploads/blog1_2.png) @Stephan T.

Comment: I added the needed lines of code, but you really need to improve the original question, because none of these features were clear in the beginning